# How to put iframe in to canvas

Tags: html, iframe, canvas

Hello i have a little question.

How can i put iframe with google map in to html ?

```
 <canvas id="google_map" width="600" height="400">
    <iframe width="600" height="390" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>
 </canvas>
```

Comment: why do you want to put it in a canvas? for browsers that don't support the canvas tag?

Comment: i need to deform a little this map, so it will looks like real paper map

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You might be able to grab an image from the google static maps api and use `canvas` to warp it?

Comment: google has a Static Maps API witch will give you a single image. will that do?

Comment: yeah, but i need able to move this map after i grab it

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to put map in the canvas try this....

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 50px;">
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d2965.0824050173574!2d-93.63905729999999!3d41.998507000000004!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sWebFilings%2C+University+Boulevard%2C+Ames%2C+IA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1390839289319" width="100%" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't place an iFrame inside the Canvas tag. You could however use relative position to overlay your iFrame over the canvas element:

```
<style type="text/css">
canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
<canvas></canvas>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

One thing I have to say though is that using frame's is normally a sign of inexperience in web development. Your use of them could likely be circumvented.

Comment: ok nice, but now iframe behavior will be not depend on canvas... :(

Comment: What do you mean dependant? As in when using JS to toggle visibilities?

Comment: I've never heard the term 'deform' before? What do you mean by this?

Comment: I think he meant transform. Sounds like the OP wants to transform the iframe using the canvas

Comment: @RyanBrodie Why would you say using frames is a sign of inexperience?

Comment: I wrote that 9 years ago @MiguelSánchezVillafán, they're since long deprecated

Comment: What's deprecated? iFrames??