# how to render video from youtube iframe into canvas?

Tags: youtube-api, html5-canvas

guys! How to render video from You_Tube

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

tag into canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not supported. Looking at [Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), there is no mention of iframes being drawn to canvas.

You might want to try another alternative from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514278/6143482).

Comment: Yeah! There is no way to get image from YouTube video.